# sql exception was unhandled login failed for user sa

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

login failed for user sa

I have been working on a .Net c# project that connects with sqlserver and I have been getting this error.. "sql exception was unhandled" ,login failed for user sa and here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;


namespace FrontOffice
{
   public class dblayer
    {

        #region DB Variables
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;uid=sa;pwd=multi;database=officedb");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
         public SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;uid=sa;pwd=multi;database=officedb");

        SqlDataReader rdr;
        #endregion

       SqlConnection opencon()
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                con.Open();
            return con;
        }

       public SqlConnection Connect()
       {
           SqlConnection tempcon = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;uid=sa;pwd=multi;database=officedb");
           tempcon.Open();
           return tempcon;
       }
        #region Insert functions

        public bool newVisitorAdd(string name,string gender,string nation,string phone,string place,string catogory,string empid,string message)
        {

            cmd = new SqlCommand("exec visitadd @name,@gender,@nation,@phone,@place,@vcat,@empid,@message,@date,@time ",opencon());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", (object)name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", (object)gender);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nation", (object)nation);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", (object)phone);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@place", (object)place);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vcat", (object)catogory);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empid", (object)empid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@message", (object)message);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", (object)DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", (object)DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
            int dd = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (dd >= -1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;

        }
        public bool newvisitorimg(List<string> imglst, string name)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (string img in imglst)
                {
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into imgtb values('" + img + "','" + name + "')",opencon());
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch { return false; }
        }


        #endregion


        public SqlDataReader ExecuteReader(string qry)
        {
            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, opencon());
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                return rdr;
            }
            catch { return rdr; }
        }




        }
}
```

any help would be appreciated,thanks in advance !!

Comment: username password for db is wrong

Comment: Don't use `sa` as your login for your app. Ever.

Comment: Ehsan Sajjad,Thanks for the reply,I found out that the password didn't match.. Anyway much thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

is the SA account enabled? if you did standard install i believe the default is to not enable it and use windows authentication, in that case you could change the connection string to use windows authentication or log in the sql with management studio and enable the sa account.

also you may want to create a global const var to hold the connection string so you don't have it multiple times/places to change